# Redirect shortcut is not working, not redirecting me on browser

Tags: python, django, web

I have a code like this

```
def maca_create(request, pk):
    return redirect("maca:detail", pk=pk)
```

The view of that page inside redirect is excecuting, but in the browser is not happening anything.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I think you forgot a comma between "meca:detail" and "pk=pk".

Answer (score 0):

[You can refer to this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

You have to change to this:

```
return redirect("maca:detail", args=[pk])
```

Comment: No, this isn't working, thank you anyway!